# PD control (PID without I) - Homework help

Tags: robotics, control-system, pid-controller, feedback

I've been given a system -

```
    x" = bx′ + kx + ru
```

and I've been asked to rewrite it in the canonical form x' = AX + BU.
I've got --

```
   [x1' x2']' = [0 1 ; k b]' * [x1 x2]' + [0 r]* u(t)
```

by considering x = x1, and x2 = x1'.

I'm pretty sure this is correct, and describes a spring-mass-damper system.
However,

I've now been asked to give the **PD negative feedback control law *ufb(t)*** for a desired trajectory **xd(t)** in matrix form, which I have no clue as to how to proceed.

-------------- I know the theory of PID control. And I know PD control equation would be

**xd(t) = kp [    (xd(t) - x(t))   +    Td (xd(t) - x(t))'  ]**

However I am hitting a road block about solving this. I'd really appreciate constructive suggestions and pointers. Thanks.

(I don't know why the equation form doesn't work here unlike math stack exchange hence bolded them all)

Comment: You can use display math via "$$".  The first part looks correct but can you clarify the notation in the second part?

Comment: What's display math and what purpose does it solve ? Kp would be the gain , xd(t) would be the desired trajectory , x(t) would be the actual trajectory.

Comment: And ufb denotes the feedback input ?